# How to read all the result of a HTML page after webscraping it?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am very new to doing webscraping using Python.
I am trying to parse a html document which is a result of a HTTP request as given below and find if a book exists or not. And below is the code I have written which is working fine until a point.

```
categories = {}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("some_url").text)
divtag = soup.find_all('div', {"class": "side_categories"})
for tag in divtag:
    li = (tag.find_all('li'))
    for a in li:
        categories[str(a.a.get('href')).split('/')[3].split('_')[0]] = str(a.a.get('href'))

if topic in categories:
    t = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(f"some_url/{categories[topic]}").text, 'lxml')
    books = t.find_all('div', {'class': 'image_container'})
    if 'Cobol Developer' in str(books):
        return True
    else: 
        return False
```

The problem I am facing is with this line:

```
t = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(f"some_url/{categories[topic]}").text, 'lxml')
```

There are 26 results in this category and the above statement is returning 20 books per result and I am not able to get to the next set of results to find if my book exists in the next set of results.
The screenshot of the page can be seen below.
[image]

I see this data if I print `t`

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">
<div class="page-header action">
<h1>Fiction</h1>
</div>
<div id="messages">
</div>
<div id="promotions">
</div>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="get">
<div style="display:none">
</div>
<strong>26</strong> results - showing <strong>1</strong> to <strong>20</strong>.
```

Could anyone let me know how can I traverse thru all the results and check if a string exists or not ?

Any help is massively appreciated.

Comment: I would look for a link to the next page, try to find it with BeautifulSoup, and then iteratively process the other pages as well.

Answer (score 0):

Whereas 'string here' is the string you want to find:

```
t.find('string here')
```